# Fetching and displaying linkedin company updates on my page

Tags: linkedin-api

I am building a laravel project, in which I wish to fetch articles from my company page on linkedin and display them there.

However, before I can consume the API, it requires me to log in as a linkedin user.

How can I get the articles without logging in?

Answer (score 0):

For a nice and good workaround you should use the API, and yes you need an account for that. There are other options, they can be very slow and isn't very stable. In that case, you need to open with PHP al the content from an URL and walk through every div and use that data on your own wat.

**More information about that (PHP, XPATH);**

[Retrieve the contents of a div from external site (PHP, XPATH)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275416/retrieve-the-contents-of-a-div-from-external-site-php-xpath)

I hope this is relevant to your question and helps you.